# Netty Detect incoming request is of protobuf type

Tags: sockets, protocol-buffers, netty

In netty [example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/portunification/PortUnificationServerHandler.java) we can see how we can detect incoming request as http/ssl ..etc . How can
we do the same when an incoming request is of protobuf type.

Comment: how much data do you usually have to test? see my common on Norman's answer; there's no absolute way of doing this, but I *guess* you could just use the reader API to validate what you have at least doesn't look incompatible; personally I would think that the rate of false positives would be too high

Comment: @MarcGravell I will append a header with type info using LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder. I will post the code here once I test it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be kind of done the same way. You will need to read up on the protobuf "protocol" and see if there is anything in the byte sequence that you can use to detect that it is a protobuf.

Comment: there's no obvious sentinel in protobuf; I *guess* you could test the first 10 (max) bytes to see if the first value is "varint" with the LSB 3 bits in the range 0-5, but... that could *very easily* give false positives; for example, a lot of ASCII characters are valid varints; the "H" in "HEAD" (one of the http tests) would be the protobuf header for "field 9 follows and is a varint"; so you'd end up having to test quite a bit of data and *even then* it wouldn't be very reliable